# Why PHP doesn't show Strict Standards error when overriding method with different signature?

Tags: php, overloading, php-5.5

I'm running on PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4

When I run file with code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class A
{
  public function f(array $array)
  {
    echo 'a';
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  public function f(A $a, array $b)
  {
    echo 'b';
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->f([1, 2, 3]);
$b = new B();
$b->f($a, []);
```

I'm expecting to get a "Strict Standards" error, because I'm overloading metod with a different signature. But I didn't get any error or any warning message. Just normal output. Why?

Comment: `E_ALL`. Probably should be `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` instead.

Comment: @DarkSide unfortunately didn't work. Only changing php.ihi has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that `E_STRICT` has been disabled in your php.ini file to supress errors such as this in legacy apps that are somewhat badly written when PHP was not standardised as it is now (though still not very standardised).

Also, in PHP versions BELOW 5.4.0, `E_STRICT` is not included in `E_ALL`. `E_STRICT` is only included in `E_ALL` in PHP versions 5.4.0 and above.

With strict errors, they are usually thrown at "compile time", so are thrown well before `error_reporting` is called, so would need to be set in php.ini

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found in php.ini line: `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`. But why it set by default? Isn't it an error, which I should avoid?

Comment: It is something you would set in a production environment, as it prevents any potential attacker gaining information about your application that they could use. And are really not errors that anyone should see beyond a development environment.

Comment: Also I had to set `display_errors = On` in php.ini to see a "Strict Standards" error

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `E_ALL` with `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`